# Restart a failing BackgroundService

Tags: asp.net-core, backgroundworker, background-service

So I have this background service that looks something like this.

```
public class MyBackgroundService: BackgroundService
{ 
    public MyBackgroundService(){}

    protected override Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        new Thread(() => new MessageHandler().Process(stoppingToken).Start();
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }      
}
```

If the Process-method would throw an Exception, is there anyway to try to restart
the background service or create a new MessageHandler and run Process?

**EDIT**, After feedback and googling, Im thinking something like this

```
    protected override Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {       
        Task.Run(()=>RunConsumer(cancellationToken)).Start();
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    private void RunConsumer(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            using var scope = _serviceScopeFactory.CreateScope();
            var myConsumer= scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IMyConsumer>();

            Task.Run(() =>{new Thread(() => myConsumer.Start()).Start();})
            .ContinueWith(t =>
            {
                if (t.IsFaulted) {/* Log t.Exception and retry x times */}
                if (t.IsCompleted) {/* Should not not happen in my case */}
            });

        }
    }
```

Comment: Put a timer and check if your instance is still alive and if not start it again.

Comment: Aha, as Beyoncé said, "If you like it put a timer on it". ...I would use that as a fallback, but I was hoping for something that caught that event/exception there and then.

Comment: You want to use `try/catch` to catch the exception right? But Here is a problem that after catch the exception, how to `try/catch` again? If `try/catch` is used nested all the time, it will take up a lot of resources, So i think use timer  is the best method for now.

Comment: @XinranShen:  Ive updated the question 

Im open for anything suggestions, try

Answer (score 3):

You can write main loop like this:

```
protected override Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    while(!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested) 
    {
        try {
            await RunConsumer(cancellationToken);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // log exception
        }
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30)); // To prevent restarting too often
    }
    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

The key points is

- By checking `cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested`, the service will be stopped when it is requested, e.g. when the process is ending gracefully,
- Catch all exception and ignore it, so the task can be run again.
- `Task.Delay` ensures that the process will not be restarted too often.

In `RunConsumer` you can just use

```
await Task.Run(() => new MessageHandler().Process(stoppingToken).Start());
```

It is usually better to use async/await so you don't have to do the continuation and error-checking manually.

Comment: According to this you are not supposed to await long running jobs in ExecuteAsync
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio#backgroundservice-base-class

[newline]
*"...Avoid performing long, blocking initialization work in ExecuteAsync. The host blocks in StopAsync(CancellationToken) waiting for ExecuteAsync to complete."*

Comment: But good tip about the Task.delay, I ws considering it, but didnt want to clutter the example, but in real code, for sure

Comment: That's not what the document said. The point is that "No further services are started until ExecuteAsync becomes asynchronous", so we "avoid performing long, blocking *initialization*".  It is the long, synchronous blocking initialization that is the problem.